Openmp and chunksize in for loop
I am using OpenMP to parallelize an (internal) loop.
The workload at each iteration is not very big, therefore more threads can induce important overhead.
Therefore I schedule the loop as static (also tried dynamic) with chunksize=16.
I expect that when the number of iterations is less than 16, a single thread is used.
Therefore I expect the the time to be essentially serial time.
So I expect that for num_iter=16 the following two versions are identical:
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,16) if (num_iter>16)
for (index_t i = 0; i != num_iter; ++i)
    // do work

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,16)
for (index_t i = 0; i != num_iter; ++i)
    // do work

The first version runtime is the same as the sequential time as expected when num_iter=16.
However, the runtime of the second version degrades as the number of threads increases.
Why does OpenMP behave so badly ?

Technically, pragma omp parallel for is a pragma omp parallel followed by a pragma omp for. The specification does not associate any extra semantics with this shortcut. So the parallel doesn't know anything about the number of iterations. Your if logic is also not universally good since the number of items per task for efficient multithreading depend on many parameters

I realize this is not a particularly satisfying answer (Which is why it's only a comment) but questions of the form of Why does the standard specify … can rarely be answered by random people on the internet. A question of the form Is there a benefit to the specified behavior? may be answerable. Otherwise you have to bring it up to the standard committee.

Hi, thank you for your answer. I should probably rephase my question, what I would like to know is how I could achieve performance with openmp in this case (inner loop requiring varying number of threads based on chunksize)

Feel free to [edit] the question if you wish to rephrase it. Overall I think you are on the right track: Use if and/or num_threads to limit the number of threads that are woken up. The specifics on how to determine this usually require benchmarking

In the question you say "internal" loop, in the comment "inner" loop. Is it the inner loop of a nested loop? Can't you parallelize the outer loop? It's generally more efficient to parallelize the outermost possible loop.

In the second version you are always paying the fork-join cost of entering and leaving a parallel region, since that's what you have told the compiler to generate. In the first version you only pay that cost when there are more than 16 iterations and the omp parallel is enabled. That cost is effectively the same as that of a centralised barrier (since it can be thought of as the join/fork of the barrier executed back to front), so will increase as you increase the number of threads.
In "the book", I measured the performance of tree barriers (so, implicitly the fork-join cost of a parallel region), with results like these:-

Obviously the performance will vary on different machines, but the general idea that the cost increases with the number of threads, and when crossing boundaries in the machine applies.
In the case where you have little work inside the parallel region, it is therefore unsurprising that the cost of the fork-join becomes significant, and more so the larger the number of threads you are (not :-)) using.
